# How to get mysql sum multiple column with where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table just like this. I want to get 
total sum of `amount`
paid sum of `amount`
unpaid sum of `amount
in a single query.

Is this possible to get all sum in single query with three column
Out put should be

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_test` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('paid','unpaid') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `inserted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `tbl_test` (`id`, `amount`, `status`, `inserted`, `updated`) VALUES
(1, '2510.00', 'unpaid', '2017-10-29 17:06:11', NULL),
(2, '1120.00', 'paid', '2017-10-29 17:06:11', NULL),
(3, '110.00', 'unpaid', '2017-10-29 17:06:43', NULL),
(4, '920.00', 'paid', '2017-10-29 17:06:43', NULL),
(5, '1098.00', 'paid', '2017-10-29 17:07:31', NULL),
(6, '9990.00', 'paid', '2017-10-29 17:07:31', NULL),
(7, '1198.00', 'unpaid', '2017-10-29 17:07:31', NULL),
(8, '140.00', 'unpaid', '2017-10-29 17:07:31', NULL);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_test`
  MODIFY `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=9;COMMIT;
```

Comment: Yes. Perfectly possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)  AS TotalAmount
     , SUM(CASE WHEN status='paid' THEN amount END) AS PaidAmount
     , SUM(CASE WHEN status='unpaid' THEN amount END) AS UnpaidAmount
FROM `tbl_test`;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/MBSTS59491)**